# How to adjust brightness for Mac Chrome Browser Stuck in 'Dim Mode'

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I my have triggered some keyboard shortcut that permanently dimmed my macOS Chrome browser and I can't figure out how to undo it. I've tried resetting all chrome settings back to default and toggling `Force Color Profile` setting in chrome://flags (from default to sRGB) as suggested to no avail. This is only affecting the Chrome app.

Attached screenshot shows safari window (left) and chrome window.

[image]

Note that I have already tried deleting and reinstalling Chrome. I did not delete profile information from `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` though.

Chrome: Version 118.0.5993.117 (Official Build) (arm64)
MacOS: Ventura 13.6
mac: M1 Macbook Pro

(edited to add system info)

Comment: I tried deleting and reinstalling Chrome to still have same issue. I did not delete profile information from `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome.`

Comment: What are the versions of your macOS and Chrome, respectively, and which Mac are they installed on?

Comment: @Ruskes I don't see the puzzle piece icon next to the address bar in the screenshot though.

Comment: Why don’t you just move the profile folder temporarily to the Desktop and let it be created anew?

Comment: It is waiting for you to decide to sign in or not

Comment: @Ruskes, while not signed in in the screenshot, even when signed the issue persists.